# creating select option with for each jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 arrays which I am gathering from a table:

```
    allCamNames = $('#dat tr:gt(0) td:first-child').map(->
      $.trim $(this).text()
    ).get()
    allCamShareCount = $('#dat tr:gt(0) td:nth-child(6)').map(->
      $.trim $(this).text()
    ).get()
    allCamIds = $('#dat tr:gt(0) td:last-child').map(->
      $.trim $(this).text()
    ).get()
```

i want to create a `select` `option` menu in such a way that in options

```
<option value="allCamId">AllCamNames - share Count (AllCamShareCount)</option>
```

As these all are arrays so I want to place all the value in options in such way that when i have the whole options
one option be like

```
<option value="345">One Cam - share Count (34)</option>
```

Plus i have a `TR` and while mapping all values in arrays I want to neglect this: `tr = $(this).parents('tr')` not to be included while mapping values.

> all the three mapping functions run when i click on one of the tr's
>   TD, so i want to exclude that TR of which td i have clicked.

```
onCameraMerge = ->
  tr = ''
  needToMergeId = ''
  cameraName = ''
  allCamNames = ''
  allCamShareCount = ''
  allCamIds = ''
  $("#dat").on 'click', '.merge-cam', ->
    $('#mergeModal').modal('show')
    tr = $(this).parents('tr')
    needToMergeId = tr.find('td:nth-child(9)').text()
    cameraName = tr.find('td:nth-child(1)').text()
    $("p > #mc").append cameraName
    console.log(needToMergeId)
    allCamNames = $('#dat tr:gt(0) td:first-child').map(->
      $.trim $(this).text()
    ).get()
    allCamShareCount = $('#dat tr:gt(0) td:nth-child(6)').map(->
      $.trim $(this).text()
    ).get()
    allCamIds = $('#dat tr:gt(0) td:last-child').map(->
      $.trim $(this).text()
    ).get()
    optionsHtml = ''
    i = 0
    while i < allCamNames.length
      optionsHtml += '<option value="' + allCamIds[i] + '">' + allCamNames[i] + ' - share Count (' + allCamShareCount[i] + ')</option>'
      i++
    $('#with-cam').html '<select>' + optionsHtml + '</select>'


<tbody><tr> <td><a href="/cameras/3158">hundegaard</a></td><td>vwc200</td><td><span style="color:red;">N</span></td><td><a href="/users/1465">Gert Laumann</a></td><td><span style="color:red;">N</span></td><td>0</td><td>2014-09-02T05:57:25.082Z</td><td class="center"><i class="fa fa-trash-o delete-cam"></i> | <i class="icon-camera merge-cam"></i></td><td style="display: none;">3158</td> </tr><tr> <td><a href="/cameras/1442">will cam</a></td><td>will_34f</td><td><span style="color:red;">N</span></td><td><a href="/users/209">will Creach</a></td><td><span style="color:red;">N</span></td><td>0</td><td>2014-03-23T14:19:01.176Z</td><td class="center"><i class="fa fa-trash-o delete-cam"></i> | <i class="icon-camera merge-cam"></i></td><td style="display: none;">1442</td> </tr></tbody>
```

Comment: show $(this).text() values

Comment: show complete code of your js click function for better understanding

Comment: i have updated the question with full code
when i click on the td which have delete-cam #id then i want to ignore that whole tr @MuhammadAtif

Answer (score 1):

Try this to create select

```
   var optionsHtml = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < allCamNames.length; i++) {
    optionsHtml += '<option value="' + allCamIds[i] + '">' + allCamNames[i] + ' - share Count (' + allCamShareCount[i] + ')</option>';
     }
    $("#idWhereYouWantToShowThisSelect").html("<select>"+optionsHtml+"</select>");
```

To skip cliked TR use this not(this) like

```
$('#dat tr:gt(0) td:first-child').not(this)
```

Comment: where is the value which i want to neglect that TR?

Comment: where to `.not(this)` ? in mapping function?

Comment: `allCamNames = $('#dat tr:gt(0) td:first-child').not(this).map(->
      $.trim $(this).text()
    ).get()`
not worked